# Resolve string parameter using Unity container

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have registered a service which needs to receive a string whose value is determined at runtime in its constructor:

```
public BingSpeechRecognitionService(
    IBingAuthentificationService authentificationService, string runtimePlatform)
```

So I am trying to manually resolve this parameter in the Unity Container using the **Resolve** method like so:

```
Container.Resolve(typeof(string), new ParameterOverride("runtimePlatform", 
    Device.RuntimePlatform));
```

My problem is that the **Resolve** method **throws the following exception**:

> InvalidOperationException: The type String cannot be constructed. You
>   must configure the container to supply this value.

**What should I do to be able to resolve a string parameter?**

Comment: Why are you trying to register a `string` in your container? Even if that made sense to do, you would effectively be telling Unity: "Any time I request a string, give me this specific string." What happens when you have two things that need two different strings? What is the goal here?

Comment: I am trying to register a string because it would contain the name of the runtime platform, which is needed by my BingSpeechRecognitionService registered service. This particular string is only determined at runtime, and my intention would be to tell unity "any time I request the "runtimePlatform" string parameter, give me this specific instance, that is "Device.RuntimePlatform".

Comment: I'm confused:  If it's only determined at runtime, then you have the string. Why are you registering it?

Comment: My explanations lack an element indeed, that string is accessible from the assembly which handles the dependency injection, but not by the BingSpeechRecognitionService, that is why the second needs to receive that particular string from the first and that's what I'm trying to achieve.